# img element is not working in Ionic React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

A straight forward image element does not seem to work in Ionic React.

I added an image in assets/images folder and gave the relative path in `src` of image element.

```
<img src="../../assets/images/image-1.jpeg" alt=""/>
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-liskov-g84wf?file=/src/pages/Tab1/Tab1.tsx). Can somebody help me if I was doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the issue here. I had to put the images in `assets` folder which will be in `public` folder.

I moved my local image to `public/assets/images/image-1.jpeg` and then access that path in `img` element.

```
<img src="assets/images/image-1.jpeg" alt=""/>
```